# flutter TextField get text using TextEditingController but got empty

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have two simple TextField Widgets, and one custom 'PublishAction' page including submit button.

```
child: Column(
  children: [
    TextField(
      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "Topic"),
    ),
    TextField(
      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "Context"),
    ),
    PublishAction(
      topic: "flutter/topic",
      message: "Hello World",
    ),
  ],
),
```

and I try to use TextEditingController to handle the text, pass values to custom 'PublishAction', like below

```
final _topicController = TextEditingController();
final _messageController = TextEditingController();

child: Column(
  children: [
    TextField(
      controller: _topicController,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "Topic"),
    ),
    TextField(
      controller: _messageController,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "Context"),
    ),
    PublishAction(
      topic: _topicController.text,
      message: _messageController.text,
    ),
  ],
),
```

but in my PublishAction page, after I printed it out, I found both values were empty

I've tried something like this, but it works pretty well

```
child: Column(
  children: [
    TextField(
      controller: _topicController,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "Topic"),
      onchange: () {
        print(_topicController.text);
      }
    ),
  ],
),
```

how do I not get empty value when passing TextEditingController.text as a function parameter?

edit:

here is how PublishAction looks like:

```
class PublishAction extends StatelessWidget {
  final String topic;
  final String message;

  const PublishAction({
    Key? key,
    required this.topic,
    required this.message,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.send),
        onPressed: () {
          print("topic - $topic, message - $message");
        });
  }
}
```

and the output:

```
topic - , message -
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you have to use onChanged() method  like below->

```
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() {
                _topicController.text = val.toString();
              });
            },
```

**Try this it will help you, And let me know any issue?**
For more details you can see [this](https://fluttertpoint.com/textfield-flutter).

Comment: but could you explain why adding this line will fix the issue?

Comment: When you type something in the TextField the input changes,  So it should be transferred  to the controller.

Comment: I found that using onSubmittd instead of onChange is more reasonable. when using onChange, the text in the textfield will update every time, cause the cursor always at the start position.

Comment: Yes, it will be better.

Answer (score 1):

here in this code you give `final` values `''` or `Empty` to the `TextEditingController()` so it can't be changed, so you have to do the following and it should work,

```
TextEditingController _topicController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _messageController = TextEditingController();

child: Column(
  children: [
    TextField(
      controller: _topicController,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "Topic"),
    ),
    TextField(
      controller: _messageController,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "Context"),
    ),
    PublishAction(
      topic: _topicController.text,
      message: _messageController.text,
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: I remove the `final`, still not work